# Using Jira Cloud with JMWE for Jira Cloud, how can I work with sub-tasks on an issue creation or transition?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I'm working on a post action on a transition. I would like to be able to get the Component/s field (a standard Jira field) from all of the Sub-tasks and then take action on them. I'm able to get a collection of the sub-tasks, but it does not appear that the Component/s field is being returned to me.

What I'm trying to do boils down to this:

On a transition from State A to State B, I want to examine the values of various fields and create Subtasks. However, I also want a transition from State B to State B to "refresh" the subtasks - if any are "missing" based on the current values of the fields, I want to create them (don't need to worry about removing any subtasks).

I can get the subtasks, if any exist from the parent, with `{{ issue.fields['Sub-tasks'] }}`, but `{{ issue.fields['Sub-tasks'][0].components }}` doesn't return the value(s) of the Component/s field on the Sub-task represented by `issue.fields['Sub-tasks][0]`.

Is it possible to get the values of the Component/s field on the subtask using JMWE for Jira Cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I had to reach out to support.

Due to limitations in Jira Cloud, in order to get the subtask objects on the issue, you would use:

`{{ issue | subtasks }}`

You can then get an array of subtasks which is complete. From here, you can iterate over and access various fields, including Component/s.